# Printing the value of a 'String.CharacterView.Index' value

Tags: string, swift3

In class lexer, the variable 'position' is defined as:

```
class Lexer {
  enum myError: Error {
    case InvalidCharacter(Character,String.CharacterView.Index)
  }
  let input: String.CharacterView
  var position: String.CharacterView.Index
  init(input: String) {
    self.input = input.characters
    self.position = self.input.startIndex
  }
```

In the output code:

```
func evaluate(input: String) {
print("Evaluating: (input)")

let lexer = Lexer(input: input)

do {
let tokens = try lexer.lex()
print("Lexer output: (tokens)")

let parser = Parser(tokens: tokens)
let result = try parser.parse()
print("Parser output: \(result)")
} catch Lexer.myError.InvalidCharacter(let character) {
print("Input contained an invalid character at index (lexer.position): (character)")
} catch Parser.myError.UnexpectedEndOfInput {
print("Unexpected end of input during parsing at index (lexer.position)")
} catch Parser.myError.InvalidToken(let token) {
print("Invalid token during parsing at index (lexer.position): (token)")
} catch { // catches any remaining errors to fulfill requirement of exhaustive handling
print("An error occurred: (error)")
}
} // end evaluate

evaluate(input: "10a + 3")
```

the result is:

Evaluating: 10a + 3
Input contained an invalid character at index Index(base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(position: 2), _countUTF16: 1): a

I can't seem to find a way to print the value as a simple integer. Keep getting an error string that even includes the value I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, `String.CharacterView.Index` is not an integer, so you cannot expect the printed output to be *a simple integer*.

If you need to print out an integer value representing the `String.CharacterView.Index`, you explicitly need to calculate it.

For example:

```
class Lexer {
    //...

    var offset: Int {
        return self.input.distance(from: self.input.startIndex, to: self.position)
    }
}
```

Define a computed property which returns `Int` and use `lexer.offset` instead of `lexer.position`.